# Entity Framework delete related entry instead of setting to null FK

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this model (simplified):

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual StructuredNote Response { get; set; }
}
```

And each `StructuredNote` has a `List<CallSchedComp>` like this:

```
public class StructuredNote
{
    public virtual List<CallSchedComp> CallSchedule { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update a particular `Request`'s `CallSchedule`. The issue is often I need to completely regenerate the `CallSchedule`, not modify the existing referenced `CallSchedule`. When regenerating a completely new `List<CallSchedComp>`, obviously the pointer is new now and hence what ends up happening when I do something like:

```
request.Response.CallSchedule = NewCallScheduleWithNewPointer;
_ctxt.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Is that EF sets the FKs on the existing `CallSchedComp`s part of the `List<CallSchedule>`to `null`instead of deleting them from the database. The new `CallSchedComp`'s have the correct FK pointing to the `Response`. I believe this is the default EF behavior, right?

My questions:

1. Is there a way to remove the old `List<CallSchedComp>` in the database instead of just setting its foreign key to null?
2. Should I even bother with this if it doesn't affect performance?

Hopefully it's clear. Thanks!

EDIT: As per request:

```
 public class CallSchedComp
{
    [Key]
    public int CallSchedCompId { get; set; }

    [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1900", "6/6/2079")]
    public DateTime ObservationDate { get; set; }

    [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1900", "6/6/2079")]
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Coupon { get; set; }
    public decimal Strike { get; set; }
    public OptionType OptionType { get; set; }
    public CallType CallType { get; set; }
    public decimal CallPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal AutoCallLevel { get; set; }
    public decimal UpsideStrike { get; set; }
    public decimal UpsideParticipation { get; set; }
    public bool ExcessParticipationOnAutoCallOnly { get; set; }

    public virtual StructuredNote IncomeNote { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And the very basic fluentAPI configurations. I've used almost entirely annotations to configure the relationship.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CallSchedComp>().Property(x => x.AutoCallLevel).HasPrecision(18, 4);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CallSchedComp>().Property(x => x.CallPrice).HasPrecision(18, 4);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CallSchedComp>().Property(x => x.Coupon).HasPrecision(18, 4);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CallSchedComp>().Property(x => x.Strike).HasPrecision(18, 4);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CallSchedComp>().Property(x => x.UpsideParticipation).HasPrecision(18, 4);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CallSchedComp>().Property(x => x.UpsideStrike).HasPrecision(18, 4);
```

Comment: It depends on how the relationship is configured. Can you show the `CallSchedule` model (with all essential properties like PK, FK/navigation, data annotations and/or fluent configuration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the case. In `CallSchedComp` class you have only navigation property `IncomeNote`, but no explicit FK property, no data annotations and no fluent configuration for the relationship. Thus, by convention the many side of the relationship is optional (with nullable FK) and with cascade behavior, which EF processes the way you describe - by setting the FK column to `null`.

The only way to let EF cascade delete the related records in to make the `IncomeNote` required:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CallSchedComp>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.IncomeNote)
    .WithMany(e => e.CallSchedule)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. So If I make my FK explicit and required, will my default behavior be cascade on delete?

Comment: Yes. You have to make it non nullable field and associate it with `ForeignKey` attribute to the navigation property, and it will become required / cascade delete.

Comment: Great I'll give that a shot. Thanks again. Just curious though, I don't specify an explicit FK but in the DB there is still an FK. I guess EF just knows to create an option FK if there is a navigation property?

Comment: Yes, indeed. The only information missing by default is if the FK is nullable (since the nav property is a reference type, thus always allow null), so EF assumes optional.